# Clearing javascript code from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I have page which contains jQuery code:

```
$('#tstButton').live('click',function(){
  alert();
});
```

And I load this page from ajax call.

When I load the page multiple times, each time  it loads the script and stores to cache.

Say when I make ajax call three times. and click **$('#tstButton')** once, then it will alert 3 time.

I have used:

```
cache:false
```

in ajax call. But still its not clearing cache.

How can I clear these javascript codes from cache?

Comment: But your problem has nothing to do with cache but on how you call this snippet, surely from ajax callback.

Answer (score 3):

You can `unbind` the event first before `binding` using [`die()`](https://api.jquery.com/die/) if you're using jQuery < v1.7.2.

```
$('#tstButton').die('click').live('click', function() {
    alert();
});
```

If you're using jQuery v  > 1.7.2

You can use `on` and `off`:

```
$('#tstButton').off('click').on('click', function() {
    alert();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can OFF your previously binded click using jquery [OFF](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function.

```
$('#tstButton').off("click").on('click',function(){
    alert();
});
```

Comment: `die()` should be used regarding event bound using `live()` but that's just bad workaround regarding event bound multiple times

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is not a good solution to bind \ unbind event every time when you have dynamically loaded page.

You can use [**`event delegation`**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and bind it only once.

Execute this once on page load and it will properly work on any dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tstButton', function() {
    alert();
});
```

`document` can be replaced with more precise non-updating container which stores this button.

Here is a working [**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0xz722ff/1/)

Comment: `bind it only once` Ya, that's how it should be done